# enum values used with std::map lead to error C2664

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, templates, enums

I would like to understand why the code

```
enum
{
   SETA_ELT1,
   SETA_ELT2,
   SETA_ELT3,
};

enum
{
   SETB_ELT1,
   SETB_ELT2,
   SETB_ELT3,
};

#define MAPPINGTYPE std::map<unsigned int, unsigned int> 
MAPPINGTYPE::value_type bijection_table[] = //<---- line 68 raising the error
{
   MAPPINGTYPE::value_type(SETA_ELT1, SETB_ELT1),
   MAPPINGTYPE::value_type(SETA_ELT2, SETB_ELT2),
   MAPPINGTYPE::value_type(SETA_ELT3, SETB_ELT3),
};

const MAPPINGTYPE bijectionMap(bijection_table, bijection_table+3);
```

fail to compile on visual studio 10 with the error

```
2>c:\Program Files (x86)\${MVCDIR}\VC\include\utility(246): 
2>error C2664: 'std::forward' : cannot convert parameter 1 from '' to '&'
2>          ..\myfile.cpp(68) : see reference to function template instantiation 
2>'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>::pair<,>(_Other1 &&,_Other2 &&)' being compiled
2>          with
2>          [
2>              _Ty1=const unsigned int,
2>              _Ty2=unsigned int,
2>              _Other1=,
2>              _Other2=
2>          ]
```

I need to explicitly cast values `SETB_ELTX` to `unsigned int` to compile successfully.

Comment: [OT]: You may use `typedef` instead of this *MACRO*

Comment: It compiles just fine with gcc-4.8.1 in C++11 mode - see [on ideone](http://ideone.com/wQN7a9) - maybe you should get a better compiler...?

Comment: @TonyD Easier said than done.

Comment: @Jarod42 the typedef is only there to avoid verbosity. I undef on the next line.

Comment: Anyway, you've obviously either got to store actual enums in the map, or do some casting in the value_type construction... if the latter's what you prefer but you don't like it being verbose, you can easily create a MAKE_VALUE(x, y) macro that casts in the substitution.

Comment: @Jarod42: Or use type aliases instead of TYPEDEFs.

Comment: I just encountered the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24570840/vc-function-template-instantiation-error-c2664-when-using-different-enum-argum. It was related to template argument deduction issues (bug?) of VC++ when passing anonymous enum as template arguments.