# VC++ Function Template Instantiation Error C2664 When Using Different Enum Arguments

Tags: c++, templates

The following codes produces compilation error in VC++2010:

```
// cpptests.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template <typename U1>
int insert_unit01(const U1& u1) {
    return 0;
}
enum {A1,A2 };
enum {B1,B2 };

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    cout << insert_unit01(A1) << endl;
    cout << insert_unit01(B1) << endl;
    return 0;
}



C:\work\cpptests.cpp(23): error C2664: 'insert_unit01' : cannot convert 
parameter 1 from '' to 'const &' Reason: cannot convert from '' 
to 'const 'Conversion to enumeration type requires an explicit cast 
(static_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast)
```

The problem is that I was instantiating the same template function using another enumerator `B1` (after `A1`).
I am new to C++template. Why is there such an error?
Are there any specific rules related to `enum` when doing argument deduction? Is it VC++2010 specific?

EDIT: Note that this compiles correctly (without calling the template function a second time using `B1`)

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    cout << insert_unit01(A1) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

So why it didn't instantiate a second function for `insert_unit01(B1)`, but instead produced a compilation error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using anonymous enums as template arguments is only allowed since C++11, so either build in C++11 mode, or don't use anonymous enums as template arguments :

```
enum MyEnumA {A1,A2 };
enum MyEnumB {B1,B2 };
```

Comment: Does it mean VC++ was wrong in not producing an error when 'insert_unit01(A1)' was called the first time?

Comment: @JavaMan : "wrong" is a big word. strict adherence to the standard is rare - most implementations will have their own extensions, or slightly deviating behaviour.

Comment: Wrong is appropriate here even if the behaviour is deviating from the standard. Since the first function call 'insert_unit01(A1)' may be hidden deep in another header file included indirectly over many layers of nested #includes (which was what I faced). And the 2nd function call causes errors mysteriously in a far remote src file without any cue for one to trace it back to the first function call.